# Array type element extracted from a JSON buffer not showing the usual properties of arrays (in NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, buffer

I send on a UDP port (2222) a message, JSON style, that is caught by a UDP server listening to this port in NodeJS. When the event of a new message is fired, the data (Buffer type) is turn into a JSON in which there is an array of nested arrays.
The variable deviceData is just a large object in which I have arrays of 150 elements in which I push/shift as in a pipeline my new data, (the timestamp + each of my values extracted from th nested arrays).

The typical format of the source data, after converting from the buffer, is as follows:

```
{"ts" : 1234567890,
"ms" : 500,
"values": [[0,0],
[0,0],
[0,0,0],
[0,0,0],
[0,0,0],
[0,0,0],
[0],
[0],
[0,0],
[0,0]
]}
```

And the code is like this:

```
let deviceData = {}
UDPserver.bind(2222)

UDPserver.on('error', (err => {
console.log('server error:\n${err.stack}')
server.close()
}

UDPserver.on('message', (data) => {

let JSONdata = JSON.parse(data.toString())
console.log(JSONdata)
let newTs = JSONdata.ts*1000 + JSONdata.ms
deviceData['ts'].push(newTs)
deviceData['ts'].shift()
console.log(JSONdata.values) //OK it displays the array of nested arrays in JSON type format
console.log(JSONdata['values']) //OK, it displays too
console.log(JSONdata.values[0]) //it fails, stating cannot read property of undefined
//console.log(JSONdata['values'][0]) //it fails with the same error
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(JSONdata.values)) //it returns  [ Object Array ]

}
```

When I try to access in any way my nested arrays I am unsuccessful. I tried .map(), .forEach() and other iterators but it turns out that each time it fails with the same error message : the property does not exist for undefined even if it states a type of Array.

Does anyone has an idea?

Note: The source message was built with an Arduino device using ArduinoJSON library but it should be irrelevant for the question...

---

Edit: I linked directly the nested arrays to a pair key-value (array style) to keep one level of nested arrays in my objects. I still cannot access the value of each arrays. For example, I selected the second element thanks to JSONdata['dev_1']. In console.log it displays correctly, the `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(JSONdata['dev_1'])` still returns `[ Object Array ]`but when accessing the first value  `JSONdata['dev_1'][0]` it fails with the error message cannot ... of undefined or null object.

Comment: there shouldn't be a `,` after the last `[0,0],` in the values property, maybe your JSON is parsed as invalid? the timestamp processing has a chance to not throw an error if values are `undefined` so you might not see it.

Comment: I edited the question sorry. No the ArduinoJSON library is quite respectful of JSON standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try like this :

```
var yourDatas = JSON.parse(data.toString());
console.log(yourDatas.values[0] ? yourDatas.values[0] : "values does not exist...");
```

Comment: There is always data in my nested arrays. It is filled with a 0 if I have no data. When I log my JSONdata.values array it is displayed as expected (an array of nested arrays) but when I try to use some properties such as .map() function it fails. I tried to put my array JSONdata.values into a brand new array declared through  `let JSONvalues = new Array()` but it does not succeed either.